# trying to join to angled plates together,one is straight 140 degrees fold in centre

Tags: geometry

i need to join to sheet plates,one is 1400mm x 265,folded at 140degrees in the middle,the other is 740 by 1400  folded 140 degrees in the middle. This piece needs to slope away from the other at 19 degrees at the fold line....
how do i work out the angles to remove the material so the larger plate slope down to point...

Comment: if you can imagine it will end up sort of like a kite shape...can anybody help me please...

Comment: A sketch would be helpful, but you may not have the reputation to post graphics.  Are the folds along the 1400mm direction or the shorter ones?  Which edges are to be joined?  Where is the 19 degree angle?

Comment: hi Ross,the folds are aross the shorter sides,the two 1400mm sides will be welded together(700mm either side of fold line)the 265 piece forms the hieght!!,then the 740 piece slopes away fro this at 19degrees (though when it is welded together the angle will be 161degrees on the fold line ,i have crudely measured approximately 6 degrees each side needs to be removed from the top edge to mate with the 265 bit...and will just mark a line from each corner to the centre at the bottom to form the point...do you understand wot i mean...

Comment: the piece of metal i need to shape when it is flat will look like a kite,with the top part of it being about 168degrees at the point in the center,will measure 700mm either side then from end of each side will go straight to the centre at the bottom(740 from top to bottom)hope this helps...many thanks...george...

Answer (score 0):

So the folds are parallel to the short sides.  Then I can put the $1400 \times 700$ with the fold flat on the table and each side sloping up at $20$ degrees from the table.  I put one end of the fold in the $1400 \times 265$ touching the end of the fold in the $1400 \times 700$, with the fold also flat on the table, so all of the $1400$ mm folded edges are touching.  Let us call the point where the folds touch $(0,0,0)$ with $+y$ along the $265$ mm fold and $+z$ up.  The $x$ axis is transverse to the folds.

Now, keeping the outer corners touching, I tilt the 265 mm fold up 19 degrees.  The request is to cut a congruent triangle from the end of the fold to all the outer corners to allow the fold ends to touch again.

The corners of the $700$ mm plate are at $(\pm 700 \cos 20,0,700 \sin 20)$.  Rotating the $265$ plate around the origin by $19$ degrees moves its corners to $(\pm 700,-700 \sin 20 \sin 19, 700 \sin 20 \cos 19)$.  If we bisect the segment between the corners we get $(\pm 700, -350 \sin 20 \sin 19,350 \sin 20 (1+\cos 19))$.  Since $(1+\cos 19)/2 \gt 0.97$ we can probably take it to be $1$.  If you rotate the $700$ plate to put one flat plane on the table, this rotates the point to $(\pm 700, -350 \sin 19,0)$.  So cut a triangle off each corner $700 \times 114$ and you should be there.

Comment: thats pretty much right except i tried marking out a triangle at 113.7x700x690.7 but it seemed way to much...i cut it at about 73x700x696 which didnt seem far off.....the plates also sit the other way so i need to cut very large triangles off the other corners so the 740 plate slopes down to nothing....many thanks george...

Comment: sorry the first triangle i marked out was 115.5,not 113.7....many thanks